# pass string as obejects route values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi I have this view wich display al my free rooms in the hotel according to the range date that i choose :StartDate-EndDate.
 I want to pass the "StartDate and the "EndDate" to CreateReservation action together with room id as object routes value.
 @Html.ActionLink("RezervaCamera", "CreateReservation", "Reservation", new {RoomID= room.RoomID }, "") and don't know how.Is this posible to  pass a string as route objects.

Here is my view:

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("SearchFree", "Reservation", FormMethod.Get))
  {
   <div class="editor-label">
   <label for="StartDate">Select Start date:
    </label>@(Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("StartDate").MinDate(DateTime.Today).ShowButtonPanel(true).ChangeYear(true).ChangeMonth(true).NumberOfMonths(2))


     </div>
     <div class="editor-label">
      <label for="EndDate">Select End date:</label>@(Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("EndDate").MinDate(DateTime.Today).ShowButtonPanel(true).ChangeYear(true).ChangeMonth(true).NumberOfMonths(2))


</div>

<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</p>

  }

          <div class="styler">
             <fieldset class="ui-widget">
<legend class="ui-state-legend-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">CamereleLibere

    <ul id="album-list">
        @foreach (var album in Model)
        {
             @Html.ActionLink("RezervaCamera", "CreateReservation", "Reservation", new {RoomID= room.RoomID }, "")



                     <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px"> 
                     <img title=CameraNumarul:@album.Room_number width="75" height="75" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Rooms",
                     new { album.RoomID})" />

                     <span>Numarul de locuri:@album.NumberofSpots</span>




                     </a>

            </li>
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using some custom `Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker` helper which is not standard. Look at the generated HTML code source. I guess that this helper generates a text input:

```
<input type="text" name="StatrDate" ...>
```

Note the `name` attribute. Now in your controller action use the same name:

```
[HttpPost]
pubilc ActionResult SearchFree(int roomID, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    ...
}
```

or even better use a view model:

```
public class ReservationViewModel
{
    public int RoomID { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
pubilc ActionResult SearchFree(ReservationViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Also take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/melvynharbour/archive/2008/11/21/mvc-modelbinder-and-localization.aspx) which discusses the differences in the format used by the default model binder when parsing DateTimes between GET and POST requests. With a GET request the following format is expected: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: This part is working for me and i display the free rooms what i want to do is when i click to reserve one of my displayed rooms to pass to "create reservetion" action the date i already selected before when i searched the free rooms

Comment: Yes, that's what will happen with the code I have showed you. You should have your controller action take those datetimes as additional arguments.